# error of permutation feature importance

Tags: confidence-interval, importance

Feature importance can be calculated by permuting features. But it seems to suffer from instability. To be more accurate about the feature importance, chap 5.5.1 in [interpretable machine learning](https://christophm.github.io/interpretable-ml-book/feature-importance.html) suggests repeating the permutation many times to get the permutation error. Also, the author's  [R package iml](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/iml/vignettes/intro.html) makes the error plot using the percentile of the permutations.

My question is when I permute the features, should I sample with replacement or without replacement? 
If I sample with replacement, it would be more like bootstrap rather than permutation, then is it safe to use bootstrap’s approach to calculate the confidence interval?

If I sample without replacement, how do I interpret the percentile of permutations? It somehow has a connection to the confidence interval but I could not find a reference to support this connection.

Answer (score 4):

In the following answer I assume that we compute the feature importance for one feature $x_j$ and compute the importance as the difference in model error after permutation (the alternative would be the ratio).

In the paper about model-agnostic feature importance by [1], the authors suggest splitting the dataset into two random halves and swap the values of feature $x_j$. This is the equivalent to sampling without replacement.

**Sampling Without Replacement**

Sampling is random and will yield different results when repeated. That's why I would recommend repeating the feature importance estimate multiple times and see how large the variance is.

We compute the feature importance $FI_j$ of feature $x_j$ as the difference in model error increase when feature j is permuted:

$FI_j = \sum_{i=1}^n L(y^{(i)}, f(x^{(i)})) - \sum_{i=1}^n L(y^{(i)}, f(x^{(i)}_{perm:j}))$

where $L$ is a loss function, e.g. squared difference: $(y - f(x))^2$ and $x^{(i)}_{perm:j}$ is the i-th instance from the data with the j-th feature replaced by a randomly drawn value from another data instance.

There is a connection with confidence intervals and hypothesis tests. By resampling without replacement, we perform a [permutation test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resampling_(statistics)#Permutation_tests), with the Null-hypothesis that the feature importance of feature $x_j$ is zero:

$$H_0: FI_j = 0$$

By resampling $x_j$ without replacement, we generate samples under this Null-hypothesis. 
When the feature is really not important, we should observe values for $FI_j$ that vary around 0.
Permutation tests are a framework to generate confidence intervals and p-values from resampling. 
Imagine you would repeat the $FI_j$-estimate 100 times, i.e. we get 100 $FI_j$ estimates.
Then we order the importances by increasing value.
The 90%-confidence interval would range from the 5-th to the 95-th value of the (ordered) feature importances.

**Sampling with Replacement**

I asssume you mean that you would sample for each instance the feature $x_j$ from the training data with replacement, i.e. you allow the $x_j$ of an instance to be drawn repeatedly (or not at all). 
I think that should work as well, but I would recommend sampling without replacement since than we can rely on the framework of permutation tests.

[1] Fisher, Aaron, Cynthia Rudin, and Francesca Dominici. "Model Class Reliance: Variable Importance Measures for any Machine Learning Model Class, from the" Rashomon" Perspective." arXiv preprint arXiv:1801.01489 (2018).

Comment: +1. Welcome to the website. I like your IML book!